How do I pass a field that is type "geometry" in the database through an API in .Net
Well, I want to return all the records from a database through an API in a .NET application.
One of the fields used by the table is of the geometry type, which gives me a conflict. I have tried several libraries, but they all give me an error. If you can help me clarify the situation a little, please.
The application has a hexagonal architecture:
GeoRegionConfiguration:
 using Core.Entities;
 using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
 using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace Infraestructure.Data.Configurations
{
  internal class GeoRegionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<GeoRegion>
  {
     public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<GeoRegion> builder)
     {
        builder.ToTable("Geo_Region", DataConstants.SCHEMA);

        builder.HasKey(row => row.Id)
            .HasName("PK_Geo_Region");

        builder.Property(row => row.Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("id")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Property(row => row.Nombre)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("nombre")
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar(250)");

        builder.Property(row => row.Geometry)
            .HasColumnName("geometry")
            .HasColumnType("geometry"); // Define el tipo como 'geometry' en la base de datos
    }
}
}

Entity:
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;

namespace Core.Entities
{
    public class GeoRegion
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public Geometry Geometry { get; set; } // Tipo Geometry de NetTopologySuite
    }
}

Metodo en el Servicio:
  public IQueryable<GeoRegionDto> GetAllGeoRegions(PaginationGeoRegionQueryFilter filter)
    {
        var geoRegions = _mapsRepository.GetAllGeoRegions();

        // Proyecta Geometry como string WKT
        var result = geoRegions.Select(q => new GeoRegionDto
        {
            Id = q.Id,
            Nombre = q.Nombre,
            Geometry = q.Geometry != null ? q.Geometry.AsText() : null 
        });

        return result;
    }

DTO:
namespace Core.DTOs.Community
{
    public class GeoRegionDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Nombre { get; set; }
        public string? Geometry { get; set; } // Mantén Geometry como string en el DTO
    }
}

Con este codigo en la librería que estoy usando que es: NetTopologySuite, me da este error, cuando pruebo el endpoint:
: Infraestructure.Filters.GlobalExceptionFilter[0]
  Ha ocurrido la siguiente excepción: The 'Geometry' property 'GeoRegion.Geometry' could not be mapped to the database type 'geometry' because the database provider does not support mapping 'Geometry' properties to 'geometry' columns. Consider mapping to a different database type or converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-value-converters for more information. Alternately, exclude the property from the model using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'. -    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.ThrowPropertyNotMappedException(String propertyType, IConventionTypeBase typeBase, IConventionProperty unmappedProperty)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.<ValidatePropertyMapping>g__Validate|7_0(IConventionTypeBase typeBase, <>c__DisplayClass7_0&)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidatePropertyMapping(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelRuntimeInitializer.Initialize(IModel model, Boolean designTime, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 validationLogger)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInject


Did you add the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite package to your project, and did you use UseNetTopologySuite() in the options builder, like it says in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial

@Charlieface And after installing the package, how do I do it in the code?

It's all in the link
